# Javascript gradual width increase

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to gradually increase the elements of 2 id's in javascript using a Timeout. I can get one working but when trying to call another element into the same function it only does one iteration then crashes after the first recursive call.

I'm passing two id's for the elements. and I want the left element to gradually increase while the right element gradually increases in width.

Heres what ive got

```
        function grow(elementL, elementR)
        {       
                var htL = parseInt(document.getElementById(elementL).style.width,10);
                var htR = parseInt(document.getElementById(elementR).style.width,10);
                var movementL = htL + 5;
                var movementR = htR - 5;
                document.getElementById(elementL).style.width = movementL + 'px';
                document.getElementById(elementR).style.width = movementR + 'px';
                if (movementL > 1000) {
                    clearTimeout(loopTimer);
                    return false;
                }
                var loopTimer = setTimeout('grow(\''+elementL+','+elementR+'\')',50);
        }
```

Comment: Do never ever pass strings to `setTimeout`, pass a function!

Comment: Your `looptimer` variable won't be in scope the next time the function is executed. Also, when the function is executed, the timeout has already been triggered and cannot be cleared. Instead of trying to clear something, you should *not* schedule another one. **Edit**: OK, with `return`ing from the if-statement you actually do that already. But you still don't need the `clearTimeout`.

Comment: Ahh true, I did not see that. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simplify this (removing the script-generation) by using `setInterval` -- this repeats the function call until you cancel it.

```
function grow(elementL, elementR)
{       
    var loopTimer = setInterval(function() { 
        if (!growStep(elementL, elementR)) {
            clearInterval(loopTimer);
        }
    }, 50);
}
function growStep(elementL, elementR) {
    var htL = parseInt(document.getElementById(elementL).style.width,10);
    var htR = parseInt(document.getElementById(elementR).style.width,10);
    var movementL = htL + 5;
    var movementR = htR - 5;
    document.getElementById(elementL).style.width = movementL + 'px';
    document.getElementById(elementR).style.width = movementR + 'px';
    if (movementL > 1000) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

[(Fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/HLKyy/3/)

**Edit**

Yeah, I guess the only problem with the OP code is that it passes a string to `setTimeout`, [rather than the function itself](http://jsfiddle.net/Y7u7e/):

```
var loopTimer = setTimeout(function() {
    grow(elementL, elementR);
},50);
```

Comment: Isn't this just a comment - I don't see how it addresses the OP's issue of not working?

Comment: just replace setTimeout with setInterval?

Comment: Thanks, that worked :) now I can fiddle with my conditionals to get what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> setTimeout('grow(\''+elementL+','+elementR+'\')',50)
> ```

would need to be

```
setTimeout('grow(\''+elementL+'\',\''+elementR+'\')',50)
//                             ^^ ^^
```

to work. But don't do that. Pass a function expression to [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout):

```
setTimeout(function() {
    grow(elementL, elementR);
}, 50)
```

Comment: Thank you, I will use that function call in the future! :D