# Gradual Increase/Decrease javascript 2 elements

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to gradually increase the elements of 2 id's in javascript using a Interval. 
I'm passing two id's for the elements. I'm trying write conditionals so that depending on the position the width of the elements gradually increase in the direction dependent of the position.

if the passed element position is smaller than the oldPosition I want the the left element to decrease and the right element to increase gradually. And the opposite if the passed element position is bigger than the oldPosition.

Note this, is an extension of my old problem which was fixed :) ([Javascript gradual width increase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19392478/javascript-gradual-width-increase))

Heres what ive got

```
function grow(elementL, elementR, elementText, position)
{       
    window.loopTimer = setInterval(function() { 
        growInner(elementL, elementR, position); 
        /* fadeOut(elementText);    */
    }, 25);
}

var oldPosition = 0;
function growInner(elementL, elementR, position)
{       
    var htL = parseInt(document.getElementById(elementL).style.width,10);
    var htR = parseInt(document.getElementById(elementR).style.width,10);
    var movementL =0;
    var movementR =0;
    if(position < oldPosition)
    {
        movementL = htL + 10;
        movementR = htR - 10;
    } 
    if(position > oldPosition)
    {
        movementL = htL - 10;
        movementR = htR + 10;
    }

    if(position == 1 && htL < 600 || rtL > 250){
        document.getElementById(elementL).style.width = movementL + 'px';
        document.getElementById(elementR).style.width = movementR + 'px';
        oldPosition = position;
    }
    else if(position == 2 && htL < 550  || rtL > 300){
        document.getElementById(elementL).style.width = movementL + 'px';
        document.getElementById(elementR).style.width = movementR + 'px';
        oldPosition = position;
    }
    else if(position == 3 && htL < 300  || rtL > 550){
        document.getElementById(elementL).style.width = movementL + 'px';
        document.getElementById(elementR).style.width = movementR + 'px';
        oldPosition = position;
    }
    else if(position == 4 && htL < 250  || rtL > 600){
        document.getElementById(elementL).style.width = movementL + 'px';
        document.getElementById(elementR).style.width = movementR + 'px';
        oldPosition = position;
    }
    else{
        clearInterval(loopTimer);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: One obvious error: you're using `setInterval()` at the top and `clearTimeout()` at the bottom.

Comment: thanks, corrected :) but still not working :)

Comment: Can you throw an example into a fiddle because I'm super lazy?

Comment: Not a solution but you should convert all those `document.getElementById` calls to variables.

Comment: I think i've figured it out but I would like to shorten it. Anyways when the site lets me i will post the solution.

Comment: heres a jsfiddle attempt to show it but I cannot seem to quite get it going. http://jsfiddle.net/2mRsG/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My previous code position conditionals were not correctly taking into account the width growth direction in terms of the position clicked. I reduced the variable documnentGet calls and added some security with the boolean returns so that it couldn't start another timer until the previous one had stopped.

I have a jsFiddle link for it but I cannot seem to get it working.

http://jsfiddle.net/2mRsG/3/

```
function moveStart(elementL, elementR, position)
{
    var moveTimer = setInterval(function() { 
        if (!movingProcess(elementL, elementR, position)) {
            clearInterval(moveTimer);
        }
    }, 20);
}

var oldPos = 1;
    function movingProcess(elementL, elementR, position) {
        moving = true;
        var htL = parseInt(document.getElementById(elementL).style.width,10);
        var htR = parseInt(document.getElementById(elementR).style.width,10);
        var left = document.getElementById(elementL);
        var right = document.getElementById(elementR);
        if(position==1){        
            var movementL = htL + 5;
            var movementR = htR - 5;
            left.style.width = movementL + 'px';
            right.style.width = movementR + 'px';
            if (movementL >= 600 && position==1) 
            {
                oldPos = 1;
                moving = false;
                return false;
            }
        }
        else if(position==2 && oldPos > 2){
            var movementL = htL + 5;
            var movementR = htR - 5;
            left.style.width = movementL + 'px';
            right.style.width = movementR + 'px';
            if (movementL >= 500) 
            {
                oldPos = 2;
                moving = false;
                return false;
            }
        }
        else if(position==2 && oldPos == 1){        
            var movementL = htL - 5;
            var movementR = htR + 5;
            left.style.width = movementL + 'px';
            right.style.width = movementR + 'px';
            if (movementR >= 300) 
            {
                oldPos = 2;
                moving = false;
                return false;
            }
        }
        else if(position==3 && oldPos < 3){
            var movementL = htL - 5;
            var movementR = htR + 5;
            left.style.width = movementL + 'px';
            right.style.width = movementR + 'px';
            if (movementR >= 500) 
            {
                oldPos = 3;
                moving = false;
                return false;
            }
        }
        else if(position==3 && oldPos ==4){
            var movementL = htL + 5;
            var movementR = htR - 5;
            left.style.width = movementL + 'px';
            right.style.width = movementR + 'px';
            if (movementL >= 300) 
            {
                oldPos = 3;
                moving = false;
                return false;
            }
        }
        else if(position==4){
            var movementL = htL - 5;
            var movementR = htR + 5;
            left.style.width = movementL + 'px';
            right.style.width = movementR + 'px';
            if (movementR >= 600) 
            {
                oldPos = 4;
                moving = false;
                return false;
            }       
        }   
        return true;
    }
```